# Differentiate between a list and an atom in common lisp

Tags: algorithm, common-lisp, clisp

I have a basic clisp function that I am making that just returns the number of atoms in a list.  The issue I am having is I need it to increment for atoms in a list that is in the list, instead of seeing a list as 1 element in the list.

The real question I guess is **how do you differentiate in your code whether an element is a list or an atom**?  If I can do that, I can send the lists to another function to add up and return the number of atoms they contain.

Clear as mud? :)

I have an example here:

```
(defun list_length (a)
  (cond ((null a) 0)
        (t (+ 1 (list_length (cdr a))))))
```

This works great if there are no embedded lists in the parent list, for example,
`'(1 2 3 (4 5) 6)` would return 5.  I need it to include 4 and 5 instead of the list (4 5) as one.

Thanks for your help.

Jon

---

EDIT:

```
(defun list_length (a)
  (cond ((null a) 0)
        ((listp (car a)) (list_length (car a)))
        (t (+ 1 (list_length (cdr a))))))
```

---

```
[18]> (list_length '(1 2 3 (4 5) 6))
1. Trace: (LIST_LENGTH '(1 2 3 (4 5) 6))
2. Trace: (LIST_LENGTH '(2 3 (4 5) 6))
3. Trace: (LIST_LENGTH '(3 (4 5) 6))
4. Trace: (LIST_LENGTH '((4 5) 6))
5. Trace: (LIST_LENGTH '(4 5))
6. Trace: (LIST_LENGTH '(5))
7. Trace: (LIST_LENGTH 'NIL)
7. Trace: LIST_LENGTH ==> 0
6. Trace: LIST_LENGTH ==> 1
5. Trace: LIST_LENGTH ==> 2
4. Trace: LIST_LENGTH ==> 2
3. Trace: LIST_LENGTH ==> 3
2. Trace: LIST_LENGTH ==> 4
1. Trace: LIST_LENGTH ==> 5
5
[19]> (dribble)
```

Comment: Awesome that is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks sepp2k.  But, that lead me to another issue... Here is my new code...

(defun list_length (a)
 ( cond (( null a ) 0 )
  (( listp ( car a )) ( list_length ( car a )))
  (t ( + 1 ( list_length ( cdr a  )))))
)

Use my example above again.  It will actually see that (4 5) is a list and go into it and count those two atoms, but when it returns it forgets about 6 and just goes back up the program.  So it adds 1 2 3 4 5 and not 6.  I will paste a trace below.

Comment: That was ugly, posted code above.  I posted before I saw the rest of your reply though sepp I will try adding the last part of that line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(listp foo)` will return `t` if `foo` is a list and `nil` otherwise.

So you can make your `list_length` function handle nested lists by adding the following case to your `cond`:

```
((listp (car a)) (+ (list_length (car a)) (list_length (cdr a))))
```

Answer (score 3):

[ATOM](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_atom.htm) is the predicate you are asking for.

I recommend using FLATTEN, a standard routine to flatten lists in lists - I present one implementation here.

```
(defun flatten (x)
  "descend into the supplied list until an atom is hit.
append the atom to the flattened rest"
  (if (endp x)
      x
    (if (atom (car x ))
    (append (list (car x)) (flatten (cdr x)))
      (append (flatten (car x)) (flatten (cdr x ))))))
```

Flatten returns a list: you can run LENGTH on the list to see how many ATOMS you wound up with.

Comment: That is a great suggestion, I probably couldn't get away with altering the original list though. :(

Comment: You're not altering the original, you're returning a new list.

Comment: You're right. :) This works as well, it is definitely a different way of thinking about it than my original approach.  Thanks for the help!